# Why calculateRoute never returns route for mode shortest and type truck?

Tags: here-api

Our team encountered a problem with HERE API while testing routing with Calculate Route for mode=shortest and type=truck.

We've also tested this not only in our implementation but also on the ref client [here](http://refclient.ext.here.com/) just by dragging points to different locations with the same result.

Example of REST request:

```
https://route.api.here.com/routing/7.2/calculateroute.json?app_code=456&app_id=123&jsonattributes=41&language=pl-pl&maneuverattributes=po,ti,pt,ac,di,fj,ix&metricsystem=metric&mode=shortest;truck;traffic:disabled&routeattributes=sh,gr&waypoint0=geo!stopOver!52.913486,6.693136&waypoint1=geo!stopOver!52.002047,19.921338
```

I would expect this combination to return successful result or message about this being exception. Also, proper remark in [docs](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently truck routing support Fastest and Balanced mode only.

> When calculating truck routes, we recommend to always use the **fastest** Routing Mode Type.

please see the documentations for your reference.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/routing-mode-parameter-combinations.html
https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/filtering-truck-routing-requests.html

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for